# How to override ServiceStack RegistrationService Validator?

Tags: servicestack

How to override ServiceStack RegistrationService Validator and add some new rules to it?

And what needs to be done to intercept the UserAuthService validation?

Here is the AppHost Config:

```
  Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature()); //Registers global CORS Headers

  RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes, requestDto) =>
  {
    // Handles Request and closes Responses after emitting global HTTP Headers
    if (httpReq.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
      httpRes.EndRequest();
  });

  // Enable the validation feature
  Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());

  // This method scans the assembly for validators
  container.RegisterValidators(typeof(AppHost).Assembly);

  container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

  //var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider);
  var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqliteDialect.Provider);

  container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory);

  // Enable Authentication
  Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
            new CustomAuthProvider(), 
        }));

  // Provide service for new users to register so they can login with supplied credentials.
  Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());

  // Override the default registration validation with your own custom implementation
  container.RegisterAs<CustomRegistrationValidator, IValidator<Registration>>();

  container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(c => new CustomAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I created a custom validator and registered it as you mentioned below but a user can successfully be created with an empty DisplayName! Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

ServiceStack validators are pretty easy to use. The 'SocialBootstrap' example shows how to use custom validators for registration in its [AppHost.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/AppHost.cs#L74).

```
//Provide extra validation for the registration process
public class CustomRegistrationValidator : RegistrationValidator
{
    public CustomRegistrationValidator()
    {
        RuleSet(ApplyTo.Post, () => {
            RuleFor(x => x.DisplayName).NotEmpty();
        });
    }
}
```

Remember to register your custom validator as well.

```
//override the default registration validation with your own custom implementation
container.RegisterAs<CustomRegistrationValidator, IValidator<Registration>>();
```

Add more rules by using 'RuleSet'. Hope that helps.

**EDIT**
It seems there *might* be a bug in the current v3 version of ServiceStack that is preventing the validator from being called. I did a quick test with the Social Bootstrap project and could reproduce what you are experiencing, eg the CustomRegistrationValidator not firing its rules. Other validators seem to be working fine, so not sure what the cause might be at the moment. I will pull down the source to debug when I get time. If you happen to do it before hand, please post up what you find as it might help others.

**Update**
This problem is due to the order of ops for plugins and registration. The Registration plugin is running it's `Register` function after the `CustomRegistrationValidator` has been registered and overrides the type registered as `IValidator<Registration>`.

Simplest way around this is to creator your own RegistrationFeature as it is pretty simple in itself.

```
public class MyRegistrationFeature : IPlugin
{
    public string AtRestPath { get; set; }

    public RegistrationFeature()
    {
        this.AtRestPath = "/register";
    }

    public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        appHost.RegisterService<RegisterService>(AtRestPath);
        appHost.RegisterAs<CustomRegistrationValidator, IValidator<Registration>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Used the above code but no error was thrown with an empty DisplayName. Thoughts?

Comment: The second code snippet should be in the AppHost in the configuration part. That is what wires it up. To help any more, you would need to show your full config/IoC to show what plugins you are registering etc

Comment: Added the AppHost Config to my question. Thanks.

Comment: I pulled down the Social bootstrap and tested the CustomRegistrationValidator functionality and it seems you are right, it's not calling. If I get time I'll debug this further some time next week, but I would suggest pulling the ServiceStack source to step through what might be causing this.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having the same issue, but it appears to no longer be easy/possible to get the released version of the free (3.x) source given the release of 4.0, which we're not ready to pay for yet.

Comment: Sorry, haven't had time, best bet is to pull the v3 source from github. https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/v3 if you want to continue use of v3. v4 is also open source and on github but under AGPL v3 license I think.